# How to find parks using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I have OSM data imported with osm2psql that contain 4 tables
planet_osm_line
planet_osm_point
planet_osm_polygon
planet_osm_roads

I want to pass a set of lat long to check if there is any park on the route - I am getting lat long from Google polyline, but getting 0 results. After checking some articles I found that the geometry column has a different format than Google lat long.

Edit: Here is the query I am trying to execute

```
    SELECT name FROM planet_osm_polygon WHERE 
 ST_Intersects(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-0.09016935738398558 52.11739273481226, -0.042808661768307964 52.14120322320574)
        ), 3857)',ST_Transform(way, 3857))
```

Comment: @BERA: added  query

Comment: Doesn't osm2pgsql import data in EPSG:4326 by default?

Comment: I have used 1.6.0 and it imported data with 3857

Comment: You state the data is "lat long" but the coordinates are {lon,lat} (which is correct, providing you want locations near the Prime Meridian, not the Equator).

Comment: @Vince: I have passed in long lat format to query as you can see the issue is it is not returning any park and just to confirm my understanding if any line crosses polygon then only it should return the value

Comment: When you mislead the database on location, it doesn't reward you.  Always define things where they are, then project them to where they're needed. The ST_GeomFromText should have `,4326))` not `)` and an additional `ST_Transform(` after the ST_Intersects

Comment: My bad, on `))` does ST_Transform order matter here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are mixing two CRS and have a syntax error. Let's deconstruct the query:

`ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-0.09016935738398558 52.11739273481226, -0.042808661768307964 52.14120322320574)), 3857)'` --> this syntax is invalid. Maybe you meant `ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-0.09016935738398558 52.11739273481226, -0.042808661768307964 52.14120322320574)', 3857)`

But most importantly, the coordinates are **not** in 3857 but likely in 4326. This statement is creating a point near 50 **meters** away from 0;0

`ST_Transform(way, 3857)` --> you wrote you have loaded the data in 3857, so this statement is useless.

So, if `way` is in 3857, you would need to `transform` the input geom and use `way` as it is

```sql
ST_Intersects(
  ST_Transform(
   ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-0.09016935738398558 52.11739273481226, -0.042808661768307964 52.14120322320574)',
     4326),
   3857),
way)
```

or if `way` is in 4326, then you can keep the input geom in 4326 too

```sql
ST_Intersects(
  ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-0.09016935738398558 52.11739273481226, -0.042808661768307964 52.14120322320574)',
   4326),
way)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right about syntax.
`But most importantly, the coordinates are not in 3857 but likely in 4326. This statement is creating a point near 50 meters away from 0;0` - I am new to PostGIS and OSM can you please explain this.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that this query will return data if and only if  there is any polygon intersecting  this line `LINESTRING(-0.09016935738398558 52.11739273481226, -0.042808661768307964 52.14120322320574)',`

Comment: In 3857, coordinates around the line location looks like `-9287, 6820348`, expressed in meters from the equator/prime meridian (0;0). In 4326, the coordinates represents degrees from the equator/prime meridian (0;0). 99.9999% of the time a coordinate declared in 3857 is within +-180 / +-90 from (0;0), it is a mistake and the coordinates are indeed in degrees, not in meters, so quite often in 4326

Comment: for the intersection, yes